# Why should we copy blocks rather than retain?

Tags: ios, objective-c-blocks, fast-app-switching

I recently met a problem using blocks with Facebook's app switching. I needed to call a block after the Facebook login.

First my block was destroyed when the app switched back ('cause it was on the stack), so I decided to retain it. But that didn't work, and I messed with that problem :/. I found a solution on [that blog](http://pragmaticstudio.com/blog/2010/9/15/ios4-blocks-2) and also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6065963/do-i-have-to-retain-blocks-in-objective-c-for-ios).

My question is simply : **why copy works and retain does not** ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Because when you create a block there is nothing to retain, since it doesn't exist in the heap until you copy it there with `Block_copy`.  This is covered in the WWDC lectures about blocks.

More info:  http://www.friday.com/bbum/2009/08/29/blocks-tips-tricks/

Comment: Ok! Thanks a lot that helps me to understand better how things work !

Comment: "However, as of iOS 6 they are treated as regular objects" They have always been treated as regular objects.

Comment: @newacct What I meant was they are heap allocated objects.  In iOS 5 they were stack objects that needed to be copied to the heap via `block_copy` (this is no longer needed)

Comment: @borrrden: Not true. You always have to copy a block if you use it outside the scope where it was created.

Comment: @newacct Ah, you are right.  However, this is mostly handled for you by ARC which in effect makes `block_copy` a redundant exercise for most (all?) scenarios.  This is what I was remembering.

Answer (score 6):

See [my recent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14650386/474896) to another similar question:

> By default blocks are created on the stack. Meaning they only exist in the scope they have been created in.
>   [...]
>   Read [Stack and Heap Objects in Objective-C](http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2010-01-15-stack-and-heap-objects-in-objective-c.html) by Mike Ash for more info on stack vs. heap.

Comment: Thanks for your answer too, your link was useful!