# What is the role of the "copy" in the ARC

Tags: ios, objective-c, copy, automatic-ref-counting

What is the role of keyword `copy` in the ARC

I find the `copy`(keyword) can be used in ARC while `retain` and `release` cannot be used. Moreover is  the role of `copy` in ARC is the same as the role of `copy` in MRC? If yes , does `copy` make the `retainCount` +1 in ARC?

And I have seen mike ash blog about ARChe said :

> you need to explicitly copy blocks that you pass as id parameters:

```
 [myArray addObject: [^{ DoSomethingMagical(); } copy]];
```

but when I test code like this (without using `copy`) it works well too.

```
NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:^{NSLog(@"hahaha");}, nil];

[self test:[array objectAtIndex:0]];

- (void)test:(void (^)(void))completion
{
        completion();
}
```

Does it mean that there is no need to `copy` block when it used as an `id` type?

Comment: The retain count doesn't increase by using copy in MRC or in ARC.

Comment: @rakesh more accurate to say "the retain count *might* be increased in ARC/MRR" as it is an implementation detail.  For NSMutableString? You get a copy.  For NSString?  Bumps the retain count by one and returns the same object.

Comment: Note that the block in your example is likely a static block and, thus, your code may be "working" by coincidence only.

Comment: @bbum: True. But what I was trying to say was inherently copy doesn't cause a retain count increase. The OP seems to have assumed that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes , the role of `copy` in ARC is the same as the role of `copy` in MRR

The `copy` will invoke the `copyWithZone:` method . when it send to the mutable object , it will return a clone immutable object , which retainCount is 1. When it send to the immutable object , it will not copy , it will return the object itself , but the retainCount +1.

So when you use copy in ARC , you can use like this : `object1 = [object2 copy];` ARC will manage the retainCount of the `object1` , when then `object1` is released by ARC , the `object2`'s retainCount will be a corresponding change. So you do not worry about the memory.

About the `block` need be `copy` when pass as `id` parameters.

the [apple document](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/Blocks/Articles/bxUsing.html) said :

> Typically, you shouldn’t need to copy (or retain) a block. You only
>   need to make a copy when you expect the block to be used after
>   destruction of the scope within which it was declared. Copying moves a
>   block to the heap

and As [ughoavgfhw said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6065963/do-i-have-to-retain-blocks-in-objective-c-for-ios/6065989#6065989) :

> Blocks are similar to other objects for memory management, but not the
>   same. When a block which accesses local variables is created, it is
>   created on the stack. This means that it is only valid as long as its
>   scope exists. To save this block for later, you must copy it, which
>   copies it to the heap

Answer (score 4):

Copy does just what the name implies. It returns a copy of the object. Say you have a mutable object and you have a pointer to it. You then reference it somewhere else in the code and ARC will assume you want to point at the same object and retain it for you. In this case if you modify either of them both will reflect the changes. If you point at it with a `copy` you will get a new object, and modifying one will not affect the other:

```
NSMutableArray* objA = [NSMutableArray new];
NSMutableArray* objB = objA;
/* adding an object to either will be in both since they point to the same object*/
objB = [objA mutableCopy];
/*adding an object to one WILL NOT affect the other, they are different, distinct objects*/
```

In the docs here:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/bxVariables.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007502-CH6-SW1

It mentions that when blocks are copied all of their Objective-C Objects receive a strong reference so that they don't drop out of scope before the block is executed.

Answer (score 1):

When you use `copy` in ARC, it does the same as without ARC, i.e. it creates a copy of the object that is receiving the copy (it creates a new object instance in memory), and creates a `strong` relationship to the object that executes the code.
This means that the copy of the object now has a retain count of 1, but this is of no relevance for you in ARC, since this is handled automatically.